# Read width dynamically using LESS?

Tags: css, less

I have the following LESS:

```
&.settings-prompt .panel {
    margin-left: -190px;
    width: 380px;
    height: 200px;
}

&.create-playlist-prompt .panel {
    margin-left: -165px;
    width: 330px;
    height: 180px;
}
```

Essentially, I would always like `.panel`'s margin-left to be -50% of its width. Is that possible to express with LESS?

Comment: How is the width assigned? Is it a variable?

Comment: No, each panel could have a different width. I could create variables for every single panel, but that seems excessive as the variable will only be used for that given panel's width (and for math for margin-left, but hoping I can just read the panels width without need for an excessive amount of variables).

Comment: Do you have an example? My only experience with LESS is using strictly the CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pure Less you can create a paramterized mixin for the panel and then use it to generate the `margin-left` based on the input paramter like below. This doesn't require usage of separate variables but just usage of the mixin instead of assigning width everytime. It also reduces your lines of code in Less.

**Less:**

```
&.settings-prompt .panel {
    .panel(330px);
    height: 200px;
}

&.create-playlist-prompt .panel {
    .panel(130px);
    height: 180px;
}

.panel(@width){ /* Updated based on comment by seven-phases-max */
    margin-left: (@width / -2); /* calculate -50% of width and use as margin-left */
    width: @width; /* assign the input param as width */
}
```

**Compiled Output:**

```
.settings-prompt .panel {
  margin-left: -165px;
  width: 330px;
  height: 200px;
}
.create-playlist-prompt .panel {
  margin-left: -65px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

[**Less Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/cJetE)

**Using jQuery:** (Just in case any future reader is looking for this option)

```
$("div").each(function() { // call function to auto assign margin for every div
    var el = $(this);
    el.css({
        'margin-left': -(el.width()/2) //set margin-left as - 50% (-width/2);
    });
});
```

[**jQuery Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/45jwG/)

Comment: Just in case, you don't need to remove and add unit in the mixin, `margin-left: (@width / -2);` should be enough (a unit of the `@width` parameter will be preserved).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Thanks for that mate. Didn't know that direct division would work.